# Qual a forma correta fazer login e registro?

Tags: android

Tenho duas Activity, a MyActivity principal e a LoginActivity, como faço pra o aplicativo detectar usuário logado quando abrir o aplicativo? E como fazer para quando o usuário apertar no botão voltar, a Activity LoginActivity não retornar para a t

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla. Tente fornecer mais detalhes, como o que já conseguiu codificar até agora, para respostas mais precisas.

Comment: Patrick, eu fiz a tela de Login e uma tela de Cadastro, porém conversando com uns amigos e eles me disseram que eu tava fazendo errado ao chamar a tela de login direto na activity principal, eu queria que o aplicativo detectasse se o usuário está logado... Acredito que só algumas dicas de qual a sequencia das activities fica bom pra mim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é assim:

```
public class AtividadeInicial extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        exibeTelaPrincipalOuSolicitaLogin();
        finish();
    }

    private void exibeTelaPrincipalOuSolicitaLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, usuárioEstáLogado() ? AtividadePrincipal.class : AtividadeLogin.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private boolean usuárioEstáLogado() {
        // Sua implementação que retorna se o usuário está logado ou não,
        // obtida por exemplo verificando se o token de autenticação
        // guardado em SharedPreferences é diferente de null.
    }
}
```

Se você preserva a autenticação entre as chamadas a Web Services por meio de um token com tempo para expirar no servidor, a condição de logado pode deixar de valer se o usuário fica muito tempo sem navegar pelo aplicativo e o token expirar. Nesse caso pode ser necessário fechar todas as as `Activities` abertas e solicitar login novamente, o que pode ser feito chamando o método `efetuarLogoffEVoltarParaATelaDeLogin()` abaixo:

```
public abstract class AtividadeEmQueOUsuárioEstáLogado {
    protected void efetuarLogoffEVoltarParaATelaDeLogin() {
        invalidarTokenDeAutenticação();
        fecharTodasAsTelasEAbrirTelaDeLogin();
    }

    private void invalidarTokenDeAutenticação() {
        // Sua implementação que invalida o token atual
        // (por exemplo setando-o para null)
    }

    private void fecharTodasAsTelasEAbrirTelaDeLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AtividadeLogin.class); // ou AtividadeInicial.class
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class AtividadePrincipal extends AtividadeEmQueOUsuárioEstáLogado {

    public métodoQualquer() {
        if (chameiUmWebServiceEConstateiQueOTokenExpirou) {
            efetuarLogoffEVoltarParaATelaDeLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

Você pode querer tornar os métodos `usuárioEstáLogado()` e `invalidarTokenDeAutenticação()` acessíveis globalmente para poder usá-los em outros lugares, incluindo-os em uma classe convencional ou subclasse de `Application` e eventualmente tornando-os estáticos (`static`).

Comment: Muito legal Pio.. Obrigado

Comment: @IsraelSousa Se achar que esta resposta atende sua necessidade, [marque-a como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Se tiver alguma dúvida é só perguntar aqui nos comentários.

Comment: @IsraelSousa Para aceitar a resposta, clique na marca como mostrado nesta figura: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/357

Comment: Marquei Piovezan, é por que estou aprendendo a usar o SO agora.

Comment: @IsrealSousa Tudo bem, o aprendizado faz parte. Mas qual resposta você queria marcar? Porque foi marcada a que não é a minha. :) Você pode trocar se quiser.

Comment: É que estou  o aplicativo e não consegui identificar. Kkk vou tentar de novo.

Comment: A sua é a primeira? Não achei o nome só autor ou não estou entendendo.

Comment: @IsraelSousa A minha começa com "Uma forma de fazer é assim:" e no final dela diz que foi respondida por mim (procure pelo meu avatar, um desenho roxo abstrato). A outra, que é curtinha, começa com "Cara, você pode guardar o usuário no banco de dados sqlite." e no final diz que foi respondida pelo leonardo (avatar com o rosto dele). À esquerda das duas repostas, perto do início de cada uma, está a marca que você deve clicar para aceitá-la.

Comment: @IsraelSousa Beleza, agora foi. :)

Comment: Achei já, é que estou usando o aplicativo do Stack Exchange. Marquei como aceita.

Comment: @IsraelSousa Jóia. Seja bem-vindo à comunidade!

Answer (score 0):

Cara, você pode guardar o usuário no banco de dados sqlite.

E para o botão voltar, VC pode utilizar uma classe chamada Intent, nesse caso qndo você clicar no botão voltar VC faz algo do tipo:
`intent = new intent(minhaactivity.class)
startactivity(intento);// isso ira abrir outra activity`

Exemplo doc oficial:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Leonardo, mas eu queria era tipo assim. O usuário ainda não fez login, então daí agora ele faz login e fecha o app apertando no botão back... Gostaria de saber como é que faz isso para o usuário não precisar logar novamente sem que ele clique em sair...